# Use wso2 API Manager on a token based custom authentication system (already implemented)

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have authenticated API using a token, but with a custom implementation, no saml or oauth or other. I would like to introduce wso2 Api Manager to take advantage of its functionality, first the user-based throttling that controls the number and frequency of single user calls, as well as developer portal, publisher, etc. Now I have my user database while wso2 am has its own with roles management and other user features. The simplest thing is obviously replicating my users on wso2 but not maintenance-friendly; I've seen wso2 integrate through saml o oauth, or custom identity provider, but my services do not implement any of these protocols, I've also seen custom handlers.Someone knows the easiest way to introduce wso2 Api Manager in this context.

Thank you

Comment: Are your users in a database or LDAP? In that do you have both users and roles?

Comment: Users are in a database.. 
Here
[link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Writing+Custom+Grant+Types),

shows the ability to create new type of grant for application, I could call the existing validation services for my existing token(mobile number in the sample) in login phase. Is that so?
I need to pass to backend API user's info. With wso2 users it's simple using JWT:
[link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT)

but I need the original user's token (mobile number in sample) to call my custom service for user info.. 
Any idea?